# How to improve a structure storing many results?

Tags: c++, c++11, polygons

I have a `Polygon` structure and a function with the following signature

```
Polygon myfunction(Polygon &pol1, Polygon &pol2, int rot1, int rot2);
```

in which pol1 and pol2 are `Polygon`s, rot1 and rot2 are rotation applied to pol1 and pol2.

I need to store all the results of `myfunction` applied to a set of polygons and a set of admissible rotations.

So, for example, if I have 100 polygons and 4 admissible rotations, I need to store 100*100*4*4 = 160000 polygons. I'm aware that I need a lot of memory, but I'm ok with it.

For the moment I'm storing them in a container like that:

```
vector<vector<vector<vector<Polygon>> results;
```

so that calling `results[pol1][pol2][rot1][rot2];` I get the right polygon.

I know that accessing a single result could be quite inefficient, so how can I improve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on many thing, my solution is mixing [`std::tuple`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple) and [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map)

```
typedef std::tuple<Polygon , Polygon , int, int> Params;

std::map<Params, Polygon> results;
```

Which maps parameters to results. In this case you can find result of an specific input efficiently.

To use, you have to overload `operator<` for `Polygon` because of `std::map` :

```
struct Polygon
{
// ...
};

inline bool operator<(const Polygon &p1, const Polygon &p2)
{
    return ...;
}

Polygon p1, p2, p3;

// ...

results.insert(std::make_pair(std::make_tuple(p1, p2, 1, 2), p3));
```

Comment: Since there are only 4 rotations, I'd say that it would be best to not include them as map keys, but rather as indices. For example, for each combination of two rotations, there could be a map, using a pair of polygons as key.

Comment: @Zyx2000 Thank you for the suggestion, but 4 was just an example. There could be many more rotations.

Comment: @888 Even if there are more rotations, as long as you are using all of them all the time, it would be suitable to have them as indices.